# Spark submit error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DirectKafkaWordCount

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, sbt, apache-kafka

I want to running a spark streaming example [DirectKafkaWordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Forg%2Fapache%2Fspark%2Fexamples%2Fstreaming%2FDirectKafkaWordCount.scala).

This is my **directory structure**：

```
root@sandbox:/usr/local/spark/test# find
.
./src
./src/main
./src/main/scala
./src/main/scala/DirectKafkaWordCount.scala
./simple.sbt
```

`sbt package` is done, everything is ok.

```
........
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /usr/local/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/test/target/scala-2.10.5/classes...
[info] Packaging /usr/local/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/test/target/scala-2.10.5/direct-kafka-word-count_2.10.5-1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 60 s, completed May 12, 2016 1:34:04 AM
```

but errors found when I run the `spark-submit`:

```
root@sandbox:/usr/local/spark# bin/spark-submit  --class DirectKafkaWordCount --master local[4] test/target/scala-2.10.5/direct-kafka-word-count_2.10.5-1.0.jar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DirectKafkaWordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I am new in Spark, hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

->Actually I think you should include the groupId and artifactId of your class when you run the

**spark-submit command like:**

```
spark-submit  --class com.balabala.spark.DirectKafkaWordCount --master local[4] test/target/scala-2.10.5/direct-kafka-word-count_2.10.5-1.0.jar
```

Then spark should be able to find your class.